# Being dropped to emergency mode after upgrading to 15.04 with encrypted hard drive

Tags: boot, upgrade, uefi, encryption

I had installed ubuntu 14.10 with encrypted lvm and uefi mode on my hard drive. There are two hard drives which are encrypted. The first contains the root file system and the second contains a sharing volume which I use with this OS and another one. Normally when I boot there comes a lot of boot info stuff and after a while it asks me for the passphrase of disk 1. After I entered it the system continues booting and then it asks me for the passphrase of disk 2. After the upgrade to 15.04 it only asks me for the first pwd,hangs a while at the boot-efi.mount step and then drops to emergency mode.
Journalctl says there are dependency problems with the sharing disk.
Within the emergency mode I can exit it and after that it asks for the second pwd. I can enter it and the system boots fine.
The drop to emergency mode and the 5 minutes it waits for the boot-efi.mount step are very annoying.

Can anybody help me?

Thanks in advance.